# Apache - Large zip file transfer corruption

Tags: apache, http, networking, transfer

I have an Apache server running on Ubuntu hosting some files available for download. The files hosted is a mounted nas drive.

I am finding that when I try downloading, via the web server, large zip files (.zip, .7z) of 100MB+ the transferred file is corrupted. The method I am using to check the files is performing a MD5 calculation. I am also finding that the file size correlates with the chance of corruption; bigger file, high chance of corruption. The mount seems to be fine, because I transferred files from NAS to the machine without any issues.

I also have IIS running on windows hosting the same files. When I download the files via this web server there is never a corruption. This makes me think that the network itself is fine.

I am downloading the files via Chrome.

I'm not sure what is wrong but I am lead to believe it has to do with some configuration with Apache. How can I increase my file transfer reliability on Apache? Or is there another possible cause of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an Apache configuration issue.

Found the solution in [this article](https://serverfault.com/questions/470403/apache-2-4-on-windows-2008-large-file-downloads-are-corrupt?newreg=feb8210ad1a14707a760a74bb83b646a)

Adding `EnableSendfile On` to the `apache2.conf` file fixed the corruption issue with large zip files. Apache 2.4 has this configuration default off while Apache 2.2 default its to on.